Could not resolve com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2
Im making an app using react native with expo, and i install react-native-view-pdf
When uploading a development build im getting the error:  Could not resolve com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2.
 Required by:

     project :app > project :react-native-view-pdf

  > Could not resolve com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2.

     > Could not get resource 'https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/2.8.2/android-pdf-viewer-2.8.2.pom'.

        > Could not GET 'https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/2.8.2/android-pdf-viewer-2.8.2.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

  > Could not resolve com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2.


Could not get resource 'https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/2.8.2/android-pdf-viewer-2.8.2.pom'.

        > Could not GET 'https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/2.8.2/android-pdf-viewer-2.8.2.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

I've seen solutions for this but for people using android studio

The project has migrated to a new maintainer. Details:

https://github.com/DImuthuUpe/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/1186
https://github.com/DImuthuUpe/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/1201

tl;dr replace com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2 with com.github.DImuthuUpe:AndroidPdfViewer:2.8.2

Did you use it in your current project ? this library is not maintain since 5 years. But I guess we don't really have the choice even if you fork it
